# Is the "-ee" suffix changing in meaning?

Tags: suffixes, objects, agent-nouns

Anecdotally, it seems that in recent years, the "-ee" ending for the subject of an action has become diluted and often stands for the agent of the action, rather than its object.

### Examples:

- **[escapee](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/escapee)** as a synonym for **[escaper](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/escaper)**
- **[attendee](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/attendee)** for one who attends (rather than the one attended to)
- **[absentee](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/absentee)** similarly
- **[standee](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/standee)** for someone standing
- **[returnee](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/returnee)** as the person returning, not the one returned to
- **[embarkee](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/embarkee)** for a passenger

I don't see any change in the opposite direction.  For example, one who has been retired is called a **[retiree](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/retiree)** (not `*retirer`), although it's common to describe a person as *having retired*.  Someone given refuge is still called a **[refugee](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/refugee)**, not a `*refuger`.

Is there any objective (quantitative) evidence that this is a trend?

Comment: The following comment from Dictionary.com appears to confirm your view: *-ee is a  suffix forming from transitive verbs nouns which denote a person who is the object or beneficiary of the act specified by the verb (addressee; employee; grantee); **recent formations now also mark the performer of an act, with the base being an intransitive verb (escapee; returnee; standee) or, less frequently, a transitive verb (attendee) or another part of speech (absentee; refugee).*** - http://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ee?s=t

Comment: 'Absentee' and 'refugee' are well-established English words. Others such as 'attendee' seem to be more recent coinages.

Comment: Recent years???  "Absentee" and "refugee" have been common since 1800, at least.  "Escapee" took off about 1940, and "attendee" about 1960.  "Standee" apparently got it's start during WWII as a term for a sort of ship-board bunk bed.  "Returnee" appears to have originated during or after WWII, in reference to displaced persons.

Comment: @HotL - Yes, I did mean to state that I suspected [recency illusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recency_illusion) on my part.  Thank you for the additional information - all quite interesting.  P.S. Can I get-out-of-jail with the claim that 1800 is quite recent in the lifespan of English?  Oh well, it was worth a try!

Comment: Just to clarify, I put *retiree* and*refugee* in the "traditional" (subject) sense of the construction, to contrast with the words used as agent nouns.  I hope my edit makes that clearer.

Comment: I find a credible use of "absentee" going back to [1756](https://books.google.com/books?id=nxi2Ua5FVMQC&pg=PA244&dq=%22absentee%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6oIaY3qDQAhVhqVQKHeEwBGg43AEQ6AEIMzAE#v=onepage&q=%22absentee%22&f=false).

Answer (score 4):

The dilution you are seeing is not a new set of uses in slightly different circumstances, but rather you're recognizing that the consistent usage always had a broader meaning reflecting the original meaning of the suffix in French.

The '-ee' suffix comes from the French past participle formation mostly corresponding the English past participle ending '-ed'. The past participle can be used as an adjective, or as a person with the attributes described by the adjective. That is general enough to include both the object of an action  (in the pair agent/object like employer/employee from someone employs someone else; someone else is employed and is called an employee) or someone does something (the man attended the conference, so the man is an attendee).

Answer (score 3):

The suffix ***-[ee](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ee&allowed_in_frame=0)*** is:

> - word-forming element in legal English (and in imitation of it), representing the Anglo-French -é ending of past participles used as nouns (compare -y (3)). ***As these sometimes were coupled with agent nouns in -or, the two suffixes came to be used as a pair to denote the initiator and the recipient of an action.***

Looking at your examples I don't see the trend you are suggesting, and every term has its own etymological development:

***[escapee](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=escapee)*** (n.) is a more common term than *escaper* but it not a recent one: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=escapee%2Cescaper&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cescapee%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cescaper%3B%2Cc0):

> - "escaped prisoner or convict," 1865, American English, from escape (v.) + -ee.

***[attendee](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=attender)*** (n.):

> - "one who attends" (something), 1961, from attend + -ee. ***Attender is older (mid-15c.) but had senses "one who waits upon" and "one who gives heed.***"

***[absentee](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=absentee)*** (n.) :

> - 1530s, from absent (v.) + -ee. In reference to voting, 1932, American English.

***[refugee](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=refugee&allowed_in_frame=0)*** (n.)

> - 1680s, from French refugié, noun use of past participle of refugier "to take shelter, protect," from Old French refuge .............. ***The word meant "one seeking asylum," till 1914, when it evolved to mean "one fleeing home***" (first applied in this sense to civilians in Flanders heading west to escape fighting in World War I).

Etymonline